# Javascript Change html of next select on change of another select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying for days to get this to work but to no avail! I have two dropdown lists. Depending on the selection of the first defines the content of the second. However I am having trouble selecting the second dropdown.

Here is the simple dropdowns.

```
<div id="advanced-search" class="advanced-search">
    <select name="Attribute" id="Attribute" class="advanced-attribute" onChange="AttributeChange()"></select>
    <select name="Operator" id="Operator" class="advanced-operator">
        <option value="">Select Attribute First</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Then using an on change event I want to define the content:

```
function AttributeChange() {
    var SearchAttribute = $(this).find(':selected').attr('type');
    if (SearchAttribute = 'varchar') {
        $(this).next().find('.advanced-operator').html('<option value="">Select Operator</option><option value="=">Is Equal To</option><option value="!=">Is Not Equal To</option><option value="LIKE">Contains</option><option value="NOT LIKE">Does Not Contain</option><option value="Start">Starts With</option><option value="End">Ends With</option><option value="IS NULL">Is Empty</option><option value="IS NOT NULL">Is Not Empty</option>');
    } else {
        $('.advanced-attribute').siblings('.advanced-operator').html('<option value="">Select Attribute First</option>');
    }
}
```

NOTE: The options for the first select are pulled from the Database via PHP.

Ignore the `IF` statement as that is already working and a attribute I have defined in the option tags.

What I cannot do is select the second dropdown universally by class (as there will be multiple select's with the same class) and I wont know the ID, as it is automatically generated.

So I have been trying to get the `next` element, but i cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: May it help! [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cj21vbbb/#&togetherjs=aktyaKhTAM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with you implementation are

1. `this` doesn't refers to element which you think
2. `=` is assignment operator where as `==` is equality.
3. `.advanced-operator` is immediate sibling so use `$(this).next('.advanced-operator')`

Inline events handler have been considered bad practice, and leads to potential issues as in your scenario.

You should use `.on()` to bind event handler.

```
$('.advanced-attribute').on('change', function() {
    var searchAttribute = $(this).find(':selected').attr('type');
    var nextSelector = $(this).next('.advanced-operator');
    //You need to use ==
    if (searchAttribute == 'varchar') {
        nextSelector.html('<option value="">Select Operator</option><option value="=">Is Equal To</option><option value="!=">Is Not Equal To</option><option value="LIKE">Contains</option><option value="NOT LIKE">Does Not Contain</option><option value="Start">Starts With</option><option value="End">Ends With</option><option value="IS NULL">Is Empty</option><option value="IS NOT NULL">Is Not Empty</option>');
    } else {
        nextSelector.html('<option value="">Select Attribute First</option>');
    }
})
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.advanced-attribute').on('change', function() {
    var searchAttribute = $(this).find(':selected').attr('type');
    var nextSelector = $(this).next('.advanced-operator');
    //You need to use ==
    if (searchAttribute == 'varchar') {
      nextSelector.html('<option value="">Select Operator</option><option value="=">Is Equal To</option><option value="!=">Is Not Equal To</option><option value="LIKE">Contains</option><option value="NOT LIKE">Does Not Contain</option><option value="Start">Starts With</option><option value="End">Ends With</option><option value="IS NULL">Is Empty</option><option value="IS NOT NULL">Is Not Empty</option>');
    } else {
      nextSelector.html('<option value="">Select Attribute First</option>');
    }
  }).change();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="advanced-search" class="advanced-search">
  <select name="Attribute" id="Attribute" class="advanced-attribute">
    <option type="char">1</option>
    <option type="varchar">2</option>
  </select>
  <select name="Operator" id="Operator" class="advanced-operator">
    <option value="">Select Attribute First</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I did actually have this before hand:

Comment: i had exactly what you have written there before excep the first line uses .advanced-attribute for the selector instead of #Attribute

Comment: And after the if i had $(this).siblings('.advanced-operator').html

Comment: this works, but when i start adding multiple elements with the same class, all elements with that class are selected instead of just the next one

Comment: @JoelKilduff, You need to use `this`, I have modified answer to use class selector